# Converting from saving in Session to Cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

So, I am working on a demo web dashboard. Previously, I had been using Session to store settings about the dashboard, but I would like to move it to a more persistent means of saving settings.

It seems to me that using cookies would be my best bet. I'm not entirely positive I have the time to work everything out for writing to/from a database properly.

That being said, I might be in over my head on some assumptions I had made about the similarities between Session and Cookies.

Currently, I have some code like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting> PageViewStates
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting> _pageViewStates = (Dictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting>)Session["PageViewStates"];
            if (object.Equals(_pageViewStates, null))
            {
                _pageViewStates = new Dictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting>();
                Session["PageViewStates"] = _pageViewStates;
            }

            return _pageViewStates;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["PageViewStates"] = value;
        }
    }
```

where RadPageViewSetting is a class with some properties in it which I am recording.

Is this functionality possible with cookies? If not, where should I be looking to persist my data through browser-closes?

EDIT: I am going to use http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx to help me serialize the dictionary and then go about serializing my own custom data hypers (RadPageViewSetting).

EDIT: Here's my untested solution. Could someone take a look at this real quick and let me know if it looks incorrect?

```
        public SerializableDictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting> PageViewStates
    {
        get
        {
            SerializableDictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting> _pageViewStates = new SerializableDictionary<string,RadPageViewSetting>();
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PageViewStates"]; //If the named cookie does not exist, this method creates a new cookie with that name.

            if (object.Equals(cookie, null))
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("PageViewStates");
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100);
                cookie.Value = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            else if( cookie.Value != null )
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(cookie.Value);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_pageViewStates.GetType());
                _pageViewStates = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as SerializableDictionary<string, RadPageViewSetting>;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
            }

            return _pageViewStates;
        }
        set
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(stream, value);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PageViewStates"].Value = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just modify your properties to use [`HttpCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx) instead of Session [and work out how you're going to serialize the information] (though I recommend using the cookies to store a token and reference that token in a database for actual persistence (it also depends on what kind of information you're storing, audience, etc.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use Response.Cookies instead of Session.

Basically in a nutshell from MSDN

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

You should be able to store what ever you like in the cookie as long as you can serialize it into a string. As cookies are plain text.

Comment: You can also use the cookie provider as a multidimensional array.
Response.Cookies["userInfo"]["userName"] = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userInfo"]["lastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
Response.Cookies["userInfo"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

Comment: Note: cookies have restrictions on size of the data per cookie and total number of cookies. Please be aware that you will not be able to store arbitrary large amount of information there. Also don't forget performance implication of sending up large amount of data with every request including JS/CSS/JPG files on the same domain (unless you manage cookie path/domain carefully).

Answer (score -2):

While the answer you accepted technically works, I think it might be easier to just set two attribute values in the `sessionState` element of your `web.confg`.

To enable cookies, set `mode="InProc"` and `cookieless="UseCookies"`.  With these configuration changes you won't have to change anything else in your code, because the session will be ensured to work using cookies (provided that cookies are enabled on the client's browser).

You seem to be unaware that the **ASP.NET Session State object actually uses cookies** by default to persist data across multiple requests, (although this behavior can be changed in your web.config).

### Documentation

- **[the web.config sessionState element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx)**
- **[ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)**

Comment: Oh man. Well, thanks! I had no idea. I learned a lot about using cookies, but I'm probably just going to stick with Session if its able to persist the same way as cookies.

If I wanted to be able to see the cookies Session is producing how would I be able to do this? The idea is I would like to be able to cut/paste the cookies to a diff computer to copy/paste web page settings.

Comment: -1: UseCookie does not persist data in cookies - it only forces usage of cookies to store session ID. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless.aspx

Comment: -1: those settings are by default, and "InProc" stores the data in memory, only the session id is in the cookie - so after the session expires (or app pool recycles), it is gone forever - the cookie on the other hand can hold the data forever